# How do you revoke all invites Discord.py rewrite, without deleting channels?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How do you revoke all of the invites in a specific guild without deleting the channels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would loop through [`Guild.invites`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Guild.invites), and call [`Invite.delete`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Invite.delete) on each:

```
for invite in await guild.invites():
    await invite.delete()
```

This requires the "Manage Guild" and "Manage Channels" permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure about rewrite, but I think this is right

```
    invitelist = await self.invites(server)
    for invite in invitelist:
        await self.delete_invite(invite)
```

Comment: What would `self` be in this case?

Comment: More of a placeholder for whatever he may be using

Comment: @TylerT the conventional name for the bot is `client` or `bot`, writing `self` isn’t exactly clear on what you’re referencing to. Plus, the OP tagged the rewrite version of discord, therefore your solution will not work.